# Find the Friday that a particular date is "closest" to in T-Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for an elegant simple way to determine the date of the Friday that is closest to a particular date. Any ideas?

Comment: Define closest for us and maybe yes.  Is saturday closer than wednesday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to slide the beginning of the week (using `DATEFIRST`) so that you get Tuesday becomes the middle of the week and then you just add the number of days to go to the closest Friday,.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET DATEFIRST 3

Declare @DateValue DateTime

SET @DateValue = '1/1/2010'

While @DateValue < '2/1/2011'
BEGIN
    PRINT DateAdd (Day, 3 - DatePart (dw, @DateValue), @DateValue)
    SET @DateValue = @DateValue + 1
END
```

Comment: looks to me like this works but with the changes: 
SET NOCOUNT ON 
SET DATEFIRST 2 

Declare @DateValue DateTime 
SET @DateValue = '1/1/2010' 
While @DateValue < '2/1/2011' 
BEGIN 
PRINT DateAdd (Day, 4 - DatePart (dw, @DateValue), @DateValue) 
SET @DateValue = @DateValue + 1 
END

Comment: As I mentioned above this works nicely and "rounds" to the nearest Friday (up or down), but you have to make the changes below:
...
SET DATEFIRST 3 
...
PRINT DateAdd (Day, 4 - DatePart ...

Answer (score 3):

This returns a closest Friday in the future:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(day, 6 - (DATEDIFF(day, '01/01/2010', @mydate) - 1) % 7, @mydate)
```

Comment: Can you explain the use of the date literal Jan 1 2010? Is it arbitrary or would it need to be updated periodically?

Comment: I ran this for a date range in a loop and I think it returns the next friday, not the closest one (that may be in the past)

Comment: if you run it for 2010-03-01 (today) it find 2010-03-05 not the closest, which is 2010-2-26

Comment: @Jeremy: this literal is a Friday. You can replace it with any Friday you want.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to determine how many days away the closest Friday is from the offered date. To help, look at an entire week and the number of days away from the closest Friday:

Sunday -2
Monday -3
Tuesday 3
Wednesday 2
Thursday 1
Friday 0
Saturday -1

Now you need a formula to return these results. Because Sunday and Monday follow a different pattern from the other days of the week, two formulas are needed.

First, here is the one for Sunday and Monday. It adds 1 to the day of the week value then takes the negative to apply to the date add. For example, Monday has a default of 2 as the day of the week value. (2 + 1) * -1 = -3. -3 + Monday = Friday.

Tuesday  - Saturday use similar arithmetic: The dates return the day of week values 3, 4, 5, 6, & 7. We need date add values of 3,2,1,0,-1 respectively. The formula to get this is DW * -1 + 6.

```
DECLARE @Date AS datetime
SET @Date = '3/1/2010'
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(dw, @Date) <= 2
        THEN DATEADD(d, -1 * (DATEPART(dw, @Date) + 1), @Date)
        ELSE DATEADD(d, DATEPART(dw, @Date) * -1 + 6, @Date)
    END AS NearestFriday
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks for both the explanation and solution

Answer (score 0):

if you need to find the closest (past or future) Friday, try this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime
       ,@EndDate   datetime
       ,@BeforeDate   datetime


SET @StartDate='2010-3-1'---<<<given date, Monday, closest should be '2010-2-26'
SET @EndDate=@StartDate+8
SET @BeforeDate=@StartDate-8
;with AllDates AS
(
    SELECT @StartDate AS DateOf, 1 as TypeOf,DATENAME(weekday,@StartDate) AS WeekDayOf, ABS(DATEDIFF(day,@StartDate,@StartDate)) AS DifferenceOf
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DateOf+1 AS DateOf,2 AS TypeOf,DATENAME(weekday,DateOf+1 ) AS WeekDayOf, ABS(DATEDIFF(day,@StartDate,DateOf+1)) AS DifferenceOf
        FROM AllDates
    WHERE DateOf<@EndDate-1 AND TypeOf IN (1,2)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DateOf-1 AS DateOf,3 AS TypeOf,DATENAME(weekday,DateOf-1 ) AS WeekDayOf, ABS(DATEDIFF(day,@StartDate,DateOf-1)) AS DifferenceOf
        FROM AllDates
    WHERE DateOf>@BeforeDate-1 AND TypeOf IN (1,3)
)
SELECT TOP 1 DateOf
    FROM AllDates
    WHERE WeekDayOf='Friday'
    ORDER BY DifferenceOf
```

OUTPUT:

```
DateOf
-----------------------
2010-02-26 00:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server solution as a user-defined function.  Will round not just to the nearest Friday, but to the nearest of any weekday (1-7) you specify:

```
CREATE FUNCTION RoundToNearestWeekday (
--Give this function a date, and the number of the weekday you want to round to the nearest of
    @DateInput date,   --Date you want to round
    @ToWeekdayNumber tinyint   --1 = round to nearest Sunday, 2 = round to nearest Monday, etc.
)
RETURNS date
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Offset tinyint, @LowNumber smallint, @HighNumber smallint, @NewDate date
        SET @Offset = (@ToWeekdayNumber + 3)%7
        SET @LowNumber = @Offset-3
        SET @HighNumber = @Offset+4
        SET @NewDate = dateadd(day,CASE WHEN datepart(weekday,@DateInput) <= @Offset THEN @LowNumber ELSE @HighNumber END - datepart(weekday,@DateInput),@DateInput)
        RETURN @NewDate
    END
```